# Squaring step variable - Batch for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Is it possible to square the increment/step variable in a batch for loop.

This is what it looks like right now

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1024,1000, 1048576) DO (
   do stuff
)
```

however instead of going up by 1000 each time, I want to go up by `2^10, 2^11 .... 2^20 (1048576)` is it possible to do that?

Comment: PowerShell is not an option, I take it?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann It probably could be. I'm using this batch file to run a java program X number of times and am completely unfamiliar with how coding in powershell would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `for /l` loops can not handle geometric increments. But you can use batch arithmetics for it

```dos
for /l %%a in (10 1 20) do (
    set /a "A=1<<%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%A in (!A!) do ( endlocal 

        rem Your code here - do stuff
        echo %%A

    )
)
```

Delayed expansion is needed to handle the changing variable inside the block of code. If your inner code has no problems with delayed expansion being active, it can be simplified as

```dos
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in (10 1 20) do (
    set /a "A=1<<%%a"

    rem Your code here - do stuff
    echo !A!

)
```

Answer (score 1):

If switching to PowerShell is fine for you, you can use

```
foreach ($i in 1..3) {
  # example output
  echo "1000^$i = $([Math]::Pow(1024, $i))"

  # start "myprogram.bat --parameter $x
  & 'myprogram.bat' @("--parameter", [Math]::Pow(1024, $i))
}
```